# angular 4+ application cannot navigate to detail page from master page in IE EDGE

Tags: angular

angular 4+ application cannot navigate to detail page from master page in IE EDGE. There's warning message in console "DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information".

However, it navigate smoothly between detail page and master page in Chrome and FireFox.

I checked that route would arrive in detail component and for some reason it will be cancelled and navigated back to master page. Moreover, there's "#" being added to the url address like " http://localhost:4200/#"

please help me understand what's the root cause for this issue. Thanks.

Comment: <a href="#"> tag would navigate you to /#

Comment: And it's possible you see the message because in IE the browser caching is disabled?

Comment: Thanks for reply. however, <a href="#"> , wont explain why it navigate well in chrome and firefox.

Comment: And I guess you have the polyfills imported?

Comment: Thank you for taking time to reply. After step by step debug, i found it's because new Event not allowed in IE edge.

Comment: Aie... Those browsers incompatibilities!...